# How to correctly implement hash insert function in c++?

Tags: c++, linked-list, hashmap, hash-function

I need to read a file and then store each word to the hash table with linked list collision handling, and count how many times each word appeared (node's value). When I run my code with small text (like 30 lines) it works, but starting from about 100 it crashes (Segmentation fault: 11). I know my `hashCode` function is bad but it should not crash. I think the problem is how I increment the value.

```
using namespace std;

class HashNode
{
public:
    string key;
    string value;

public:
    HashNode(string key, int value)
    {
        this->key = key;
        this->value = value;
    }
    friend class HashTable;
};

class HashTable {
    private:
        list<HashNode> *buckets; 
        int size;               
        int capacity;           
        int collisions;

    public:
        HashTable(int capacity){
            buckets = new list<HashNode>[capacity];
            this->capacity = capacity;
            this->size = 0;
            this->collisions = 0;
        }
        ~HashTable()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
                buckets[i].clear();

            delete[] this->buckets;
        }
        int hashCode(string key)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < key.length(); k++)
                sum = sum + int(key[k]);
            return sum % capacity;
        }
        void insert(string key)
        {
            int value=0;
            int index = hashCode(key) % this->capacity; 

            for (list<HashNode>::iterator it = buckets[index].begin(); it != buckets[index].end(); ++it)
                if (it->key == key)
                {
                    it->value+=1; 
                    return;
                }
            if (buckets[index].size() > 0)
                collisions++;

            buckets[index].push_back(HashNode(key, value)); 
            this->size++;                                   
        }

        int getCollisions()
        {
            return this->collisions;
        }

};

int main() {
    string user_input;
    string word;
    ifstream inFile;
    string parameter;
    string command;
    HashTable object(80000);
    inFile.open("file.txt");
    cout << "Welcome " << endl;
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cout << "Unable to open the file";
        exit(1); 
    }
    listOfCommand();
    while (inFile >> word)
    {   
        object.insert(word);
    }
}
```

What can cause this crash? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? It will show the place of crash. Please post a [mcve] if you need help. The problem I see is using a raw pointer to store an array, why not use `vector`?

Comment: where do you allocate the list that `list<HashNode> *buckets;` is supposed to point to?

Comment: If you want a list of `HashNodes` the member should be `list<HashNode>` (no pointer). If you want a dynamic array of lists of `HashNode` it should be a `std::vector<std::list<HashNode>>`. A `list<HashNode>*` rarely makes sense

Comment: the code works with around 30 lines, my question is that why it is not working with larger number of words in a text

Comment: please post a [mcve]. We cannot know what is wrong with code you do not show. The code you posted misses essential details, if they are also not present in your real code, that would explain a lot, but how your real code looks like we cannot know

Comment: also if your code has undefined behavior then "it works for 30 lines" does not help. Appearing to work under some conditions and blowing up when the moon is in a different phase is typical for ub

Comment: You are focused on this "30 lines" criterion. Have you rigorously confirmed this hypothesis? Based on how others debug their programs, it is reasonably likely that you might have jumped to a conclusion.

Comment: Thanks i posted all my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely char is signed in your system, so converting it to integer in line `sum = sum + int(key[k]);` results in negative value, and then you get segmentation fault when try to get `buckets[index]` with negative index.

A quick way to fix it would be at first to convert `key[k]` to unsigned char, and only then to int:

```
for (int k = 0; k < key.length(); k++) {
    unsigned char c = static_cast<unsigned_char>(key[k]);
    sum = sum + static_cast<int>(c);
}
```

Comment: Seems a bit roundabout. It's the index that is not allowed to be negative, so wouldn't it make more sense to change `sum` (and `index`, `size`, and `capacity`) from `int` to `unsigned` and not need an additional cast?